# nginx rewrite transparent rewrite from root to subdomain

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, nginx

So I want my default landing page to be www.example.com/blog rather than www.example.com, however, I wouldn't want a rewrite, just have www.example.com point to www.example.com/blog

For the life of me, I can't get the rewrites to work right.

I tried

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(/)$/blog permanent;
}
```

I'm obviously floundering but I WILL learn regex as a result.

So can someone please help me fixt this regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand regex, but am not familiar with nginx

I think you might want something like this instead:

```
rewrite ^\/$ /blog
```

meaning anything that starts and ends with a forward slash, replace with /blog.
you may need to escape the forward slash in "/blog" too:

```
rewrite ^\/$ \/blog
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the first one.  For the grand cookie award, can you offer any suggestions on good sites to get one up to speed on the dark arts of the regex?

Comment: @SteveMustafa, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) has some examples and some good descriptions. I mostly use something like [this](http://www.hci-matters.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/regex_chart_barnes150dpi.png) as a reference. I also suggest using the firefox regular expression tester addon to test your regex in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
rewrite ^$ /blog permanent;
```

Or this?

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /blog permanent;
}
```

Comment: The second one worked-ish.  I started getting a too many redirects error